# Why the noises in the new furnace?

Tags: hvac

A company installed a new HVAC system 2 weeks ago. The furnace is a [Carrier Infinity 58TN](https://www.carrier.com/residential/en/us/products/furnaces/58tn/).

Two days ago I noticed a low key constant noise from the furnace in the morning around 6:20 am. The noises were loud enough to draw my attention. I went in and opened the furnace door/outer cover and tried to see where the noise comes from. It seems it is from the box where the blower is located, maybe furnace. I am not a mechanic. Then I gently tapped on the covers, the noise stopped. I thought this may be some kind of vibrations. But this morning around the same time, I heard the noise again. I took off the door and tapped the cover over the blower/furnace, the noise stopped.

Does anybody have the same problem. I plan to call the installation company after the 4th holiday but just wanted to see if this maybe just a simple thing that can be resolved by myself.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Its under warranty, so you want them to do it (not you). Even if it is easy. Sometimes there may be a lose screw that was dropped or a warranty card, etc. It happens all the time. Record it with a phone or something, and play it for them.

Comment: @noybman is right, get them back to do it especially if it is under warranty. I had a similar situation and it was just a piece of matting (from the access panel) that was loose and flapping. It took the tech like 15min all said and done to fix it. But my warranty is intact.

Comment: Thank you. I called them today. The girl taking the phone was yawning. Did she stay up all night July 4th evening? Then she said she will send a technician to check. Last sentence was "if it was found not a manufacturer's issue, we charge you." She did scare me. We invested a lot on this new HVAC system. Now I have this noise issues, which is already worrying me somewhat. Now she is telling me I might have to pay it if the technician says it is my fault.

Comment: My contract says, I have 2 year labor warranty and 10 year manufacturer's parts warranty. I sent them the video with the noise. No one has responded. I was hesitating before I hired this company. I keep my fingers crossed.

Comment: Your response should be something along the lines of, "manufacturer issue, installation issue, or pretty much anything else you are not charging me. You just installed it, its making a noise it shouldn't be, this should be rectified without question."

Comment: Thank you. I have been checking the noise throughout the day during last a few days. When room temperatures go below 74F in the evening, which we set on thermostat, the system stopped working. It is very quiet with minimal sounds. But 40-50 minutes later, the noise suddenly starts until next morning when temperatures go above 74F. The noise sounds like constant low frequency vibrations like ”mmmm—” from the lower part of the system (blower?). It is not extremely loud, but I can notice it even from upstairs, especially in the evening.

Comment: They will send someone. I hope they know what is going on and are able to fix it. May need some kind of cushion? The system directly touches to the ground. This is an 18 SEER, hybrid, using propane and heat pump, new model from Carrier: 58TNOA110C21-20 (furnace).

Comment: 2 days after the "fixed" the problem, the noise restarted. Contacted them a few days ago and haven't receive the response. I will ask them again. Can any expert help to listen to the noise? If so, please leave your email, I will send the video (30-40 seconds) to you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible it is wind noise coming through the vent pipes?

Answer (score 1):

Called Carrier and talked to a technician. They said it could be transformer or fan motor. They need to be replaced. Will see the company tomorrow.  Keep my fingers crossed.

A technician came. He found out there was a screw between new unit and the return of air duct. He took it out and screwed the two parts together at the base and taped them also. The noise has disappeared since then.

Comment: Hi @user10277759, it seems that you were able to get your problem resolved and that's great news! I took a moment to [edit] the resolution into the answer you posted to make it an actual answer. If you would come give this answer a check-mark, then others will know that there's a solution here if they happen to run into a similar problem, and this will help them out.